# Displaying DirectX (SharpDX.Windows.RenderForm) within a WPF appication

Tags: c#, wpf, directx

We try to display a live stream of an rtsp camera within a WPF application.
Performance is critical in our application, and we try to display a directX window within the WPF application.

My code looks as following:

```
fn = @"rtsp://192.168.4.104:554/stream0"; //Camera url
var player = Player.Create(fn);
```

[image]

The constructor of the player looks as following:

[image]

and the play method of the player looks as following:

[image]

Remember that the form data member is of type:

[image]

The result when I run the program is the following SharpDX window that indeed displays the live stream of the rtsp camera:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to assimilate the directX (SharpDX.Windows.RenderForm) within my WPF appication. I'm looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [RenderControl](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Desktop/RenderControl.cs) instead, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf-by-using-xaml). 
You create a RenderControl and host it inside your WPF XAML by the means of [WindowsFormsHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?view=netframework-4.8) Class.